# Why are my pmr-aware containers copied instead of moved?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++17, allocator

I'm trying out these new pmr thingies, and stuff seems really interesting.

So in my example I'm hooking up a `monotonic_buffer_resource` to a buffer and overlay it with a logging resource to gain insight on what allocations are going on. Then I'm creating a `pmr::vector` using that resource and pushing back my pmr aware container type (which is essentially just a wrapper over a `pmr::string`.

Now I initialize the temporaries in the vector initializer list with my memory resource and pass them to std::vector. What I thought would happen was that vector would move these objects in place, instead they're *copied*! I thought that temporaries are always flagged as rvalues when passed into constructors, so I'm a bit surprised. On another note, it also doesn't help when I specifically std::move() these objects. What is going on?

[LiveDemo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISQAcpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSAGykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCVzJdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BgbaY9sUMjc0EpVGx8Um2TS1teZ0KE4PhwxWj1QCUtqhexMjsHOYAzOHI3lgA1CZ7bgBudUTE59gmGgCC%2B4fHmGcXbCwkAJ4A%2BsRMAoNltMPdHi8zAcGEcvKdzm5msQmL8Ic9XrD3p83MhZvhUOiXs9ZsQvA4TikWMR/kwAO7NTD/NCCJgLO4YgDsVmeJz5Jy8GSMJzEtFQolu/wIvxSH3OABETviQCAqQlVZ5fj9iCkEHhkLTaGKJSREcqQDFfgRwXsHnsecSnvyTgB6ABUJwcJAUJzdLshkOdLpdJywVCYXloBED/LVtIZQOZsjZEWIEBWJxAlOp8cZSdZ7JM3NF4qYkulsqLVk58qLiqrdddIaw9GAZY%2BRBFTE9AlJ5NuAd5/MwqhStH1hGzNPpeZZTXZEBZsxFRtL5ZlHxLyBWMedfKzpP%2BEHMZgAEt0xScxcLSeFgGAH4%2BT6QV8aMw2h3vKcRwgQqMezDMMMIyjHsGD7L1iE9UVMHQB8TAAVjcBgTx3e1dzOGtBydflgx7FI0U/Jsp1zRM5xTeJF17AgSJnMjk0LMxEnfPZFWAyNo3QjEiLjOimXIhclxo3iE34hjU3MRITlQAgEHiF8tzLEgpQ3V9xU%2BetuTrd8iOdA8CBpCAZLk4gADpDwU1dt0wh0vz5FIf0Ef8Tw8AiwIg25oKNWD4KQlDALQ2z%2BTrbCgxDH5rgwkTZ3EyjovogsJKYyTpNk%2BIMwYVAR22FJo10/l9JpKtzQizAjLSszDzWVKTNM4BMAIQ1jSUtN3ywoiPxwr8HN/ZzAMiLLVBymjSvcgz%2BxILz6DgsBEOQ1DziCvkQu4rraNE/N51TCB4rExL4kklLjPksa1JNGkK3BJizp3fL9yVAyjxK1BrnK2qqsst8MM6uzv16gCzCEWVkDwGhkBOUahLJSCpp82a/IWri1pWx0wpFBQMmACI2EEULYxzPjNoou5rtQWUUQHViqPA4SCY2gSkqk4gEAUFi2MwcMOMWqK6Zi/aSaksn4hahUdt5hKtoO5LruZ1mNNDDmQM4h0MIAP12omFzZhXOajbnVudRT11lE56sao2SHTU6frsoECE2BgHppOqGqatdLcC772tR/lzTVFVbxvR75ZPc9VyvARgCdu9HyfQD9ZeLCkewo4mAxk4QlQYBgDvAAlYFQW2TNKS8GJx3Bv3qRVb4/kBAvNm2AMtOeFJS/LkAMMz7O8/rsEIEr9Ua%2BIAEgRBBuPjdLwGCwYhaF%2BO867HsEMyzKeZ7nhfR8LpkqzX%2BIN6MRft8bKtMNrVaesudsO6Iy5UDwdBfXQVA3YlMqMgALyZGjLWtBQX0/t/FceAsYZhevEH8CJm5rWdD1JyAMnhWTLHeM4ZgEKP1/sCXy81AIvkwazBOv07YOwFNPfe89D5b3Hv8AAtPcI2ZV8GWRAQwT2HVvYYTvg/UML8sAMIgFw9AboUgALwF/KUJwmFKjEUAsQLC2pLT3HvWeFDgBH2oXQ20fCkHWh2ngq0wJmGgMIcFDhREYioE8Dw/4eAFD/EwAARy8GIfuBB0Aqn9iAIeI9e5FyEkdCqGYhInEytlTAuVpLXGIJAuU0CiENRIcog%2BaiqFglofcWx9inEuOOsQNhyMzFrQHtXTA2ofFL22B6JJqj1FpITiFZOzxfwQxTOmJuijzTIlRGaNxKpMEvjMBoMwkh7iSK8FQExfJileIEDJAQ%2Bp/gxHGVQeItSi4VAUFWJZVBTLoDLEwdMeDxnmRkW0pOKsiJdxzkYfOFSPhihSb48EWkmIbIaRcopvTVRVxANcSCiINYMwOraE4lxT6n0BbFO43JUGJAeWs558oXyQv5uCpi8LUmNxrGfF8kkMVPPeU3eUHA1i0E4AhXgfgOBaFIKgTgbhrDWCVNvVBeweCkAIJoElawADWIAEKSFMokMwUgNAAE4xUisSJyLgQz9CcEkJSrltLOC8AUCADQHKuVrDgLAGAiAUCoBYCkOg8kKBUWNaahIwAuC2r4HQa0xB1UQBiMqmI4Rmi/E4OytALAcYEAAPIMDnsqrALBDDAHENS3g%2BAgT1GuOq6NwRVB1C8NaZVv5ujKvHDEFEw8PBYGVQZPALBvUkr4AYYACgABqeBMB0gDbKKl7L%2BCCBEGIdgUgZCCEUCodQSbdBcH0BGlAjLLD6DwDEdVkA1hk16ImmhND8QKlMJYawXBOQnBoQGswarug3CyC4aeUw/BDtCAscolQ9CFEyAIE9170i3oYEMS9ywug9AaHMe9Q7aj1AEP0FoL6RhVHGAMb9oHAMXuAxINYdy9AGUwDsHgpLyVKqTXSjgqgAiJBoYkSQptkDg1taZLgJwIAMrXeOk4uBCCTX2EOk4HhLX0CgvRlYvBOXRpWLy/lmqyUcEVaQUtkg9imT2AhTkexEjickGYSTYrJAIVIFSmlGG1Uaq1Vx0guqDUbAIK3Ag5BKC%2BpNSxyIrAdhYZw3hz0BhhQQHGgwHl7Hgj4FuA/PQrbhCiHEF2rzva1DKsHaQOkKIUhlpQxwClynlUYYDWmgz0kqAnCs7h/DwBCMnGI6R8jRrTPxFZVwFznGtDcdIHJJgM9KCRcE6WhCiQhWyek3hiTTENAISUyp3ganbAaZK9y0gfLFNic5AEBCYqNAaFG3sMwAQxVBH43sNDqnVWadK5F3dMX0Orf62VqJGRnCSCAA%3D%3D)

```
struct pmr_aware_container
{
    using allocator_type = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

    /* ctors */

    // default
    pmr_aware_container() : pmr_aware_container{allocator_type{}} {} // delegate to aa constructor

    explicit pmr_aware_container(const allocator_type alloc)
        : str_("Hello long string!!!", alloc) {
        printf("default constructor called!\n");
    }

    // copy
    // pmr_aware_container(const pmr_aware_container&) = default;

    pmr_aware_container(const pmr_aware_container& other, allocator_type alloc = {}) 
        : str_(other.str_, alloc) {
        printf("Copy constructor called!\n");
    }

    // move
    pmr_aware_container(pmr_aware_container&& other) noexcept
        : str_{std::move(other.str_), other.get_allocator() }
    {
        printf("Noexcept move constructor called!\n");
    }

    pmr_aware_container(pmr_aware_container&& other, const allocator_type& alloc)
        : str_(std::move(other.str_), alloc)
    {
        printf("Specific move constructor called!\n");
    }

    // assignement

    pmr_aware_container& operator=(const pmr_aware_container& rhs) = default;
    pmr_aware_container& operator=(pmr_aware_container&& rhs) = default;

    ~pmr_aware_container() = default;

    allocator_type get_allocator() const {
        return str_.get_allocator();
    }

    std::pmr::string str_ = "Hello long string!!!";
};


class LoggingResource : public std::pmr::memory_resource
{
public:
    LoggingResource(std::pmr::memory_resource *underlying_resource) : underlying_resource_{underlying_resource} { }

private:
    void *do_allocate(size_t bytes, size_t align) override {
        printf("Allocating %d bytes!\n", bytes);
        return underlying_resource_->allocate(bytes, align);
    }

    void do_deallocate(void*p, size_t bytes, size_t align) {
        underlying_resource_->deallocate(p, bytes, align);
    }

    bool do_is_equal(std::pmr::memory_resource const& other) const noexcept override {
        return underlying_resource_->is_equal(other);
    }

    std::pmr::memory_resource* underlying_resource_;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<std::byte, 2024> buf;
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mbs{buf.data(), buf.size()};

    LoggingResource log_resource{&mbs};

    std::pmr::vector<pmr_aware_container> v{ { pmr_aware_container{ &log_resource}, pmr_aware_container{ &log_resource} }, &log_resource};
}
```

Output:

```
Allocating 21 bytes!
default constructor called!
Allocating 21 bytes!
default constructor called!
Allocating 80 bytes!
Allocating 21 bytes!
Copy constructor called!
Allocating 21 bytes!
Copy constructor called!
```

Resources used in progress:

[Creating Allocator-Aware Types by Jason Turner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LAsqp7UrNs&list=PLs3KjaCtOwSYX3X0L36NgwK0pxZZavDSF&index=3)

[std::pmr Comes With a Cost by David Sankel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLbXjNrAjbc)

[Allocators: The Good Parts by Pablo Halpern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3dz-AKOVL8)

**Bonus Question**:

I can see from the assembly that the LoggingResource still contains a vtable and hence is not devirtualized. Can I do something to encourage this? I have seen that there was a major improvement in this area from gcc 9 to gcc 11, whereas in gcc 9 even the monotonic_buffer_resource still created a vtable. Anyone knows what I have to do to make the vtable go away for my a custom memory resource?

Answer (score 2):

The copy constructor is used because you cannot move elements out of a `std::initializer_list`. This is a long-standing issue with `std::initializer_list` since the days of C++11; there have been several proposals to support move semantics, but none that are close to being accepted. Too bad...

If you rewrite your code like this, you'll see `pmr_aware_container(pmr_aware_container&&, const allocator_type&)` being called:

```
std::pmr::vector<pmr_aware_container> v{&log_resource};
v.push_back(std::move(elem1));
v.push_back(std::move(elem2));
```

Comment: Thank you! I was actually aware of that but I temporarily forgot. So in case of pmr this means never use initializer lists? Thats actually too bad, especially for creating user-friendly APIs. Guess I have to wrap everything now :/

Comment: @glades If you need move semantics, don't use `std::initializer_list`. It's not an issue of whether you're using polymorphic allocators or not.

Comment: True. Would you happen to know the answer to the bonus question as well? :)

Comment: @glades No, sorry. I would suggest posting it as a separate question to draw more attention to it.

Comment: Ty, I did so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254236/how-to-achieve-total-devirtualization-of-custom-pmr-allocators