# How to achieve total devirtualization of custom pmr allocators?

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator, c++pmr, devirtualization

Compare the following compiling draft for a project that uses C++ polymorphic memory sources. To see what's going on I overlayed a `std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource` with my LoggingResource:

[LiveDemo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGwapK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgABykAA6oCoRODB7evgFBaRmOAmER0SxxCcl2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn6Btpj2xQwNTQSlUbHxSbaNza15HQrjA%2BFDFSOJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDM4cjeWADUJrtuAG61RMRn2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2BdsLCQAngD6xEwCnWm0wdwezzM%2BwYhy8JzObiaxCYP3BTxeMLeHzcyBm%2BFQaOeTxmxC8DmOKRYxD%2BTAA7k1MH80IImPNbuiAOxWJ7HXnHLwZIzHMS0VCiG5/Ag/FLvM4AEWOeJAIEpCRVnh%2B32IKQQeGQNNoovFJARSpAMR%2BBDBu3uu25RMefOOAHoAFTHBwkBTHV3OiEQp3O53HLBUJheWgEAN81U0%2BmApmyVkRYgQZbHEAUqlxhmJllskxckVipgSqUywtWDlywsKyu1l3BrD0YCl95EYVMD0CElkm7%2Bnl8zCqFK0PWELPUum55mNNkQZkzYWGktl6XvYvIZbRp28zMkv4QcxmAASXVFx1FQpJ4WAYHvD%2BPpGXRvT9cHu4pxHCBCoR7MZihuGkbdgwvaesQHoipg6D3iYACsbgMMe252jupzVgOjp8kG3YpKiH6NpOOYJrOybxAuPYEMR06kUmBZmP4b67AqQERlGaHooRsa0YyZHzou1E8fGfH0Sm5j%2BMcqAEAg8TPpupYkJK64vmKHx1lytZvoRTr7gQ1IQNJsnEAAdAe8krluGH2p%2BvIpN%2Bgh/seHj4aB4E3FBhowXBiHIQBqE2XytZYYGwbfFc6HCTOYkUVFdH5uJjESVJMnxOmDCoMOWwpFGOl8np1KVma4WYIZqWmQeqwpcZJnAJgBAGkaimpm%2BmGEe%2B2GfvZP5OQBkSZao2XUSVbn6X2JCefQsFgAhSEoWcgW8sFXGdTRIl5nOKYQHFokJfEEnJUZcmjapxrUuWYKMad255Xuir6YexWoFcZU1ZVFmvuhHW2V%2BPX/mYQgysgeA0MgxwjYJpIQZN3kzb582caty0OqFwoKBkwARGwgghTG2a8Rt5G3FdqAysi/YsZRYFCfj638YlknEAgCjMaxmBhuxC2RbT0V7cTkmk/EzXyttPPxZt%2B1JVdTMs%2BpIbs8BHH2uhAB%2BO2E/OrPyxzkZcytToKWuMrHHVDWGyQaYnd9tmAgQGwMPd1K1fVjWrhbAVfW1KN8maqrKje14PXLx5niul4CMAju3g%2Bj4AXrzyYYjWGHEw6PHCEqDAMAt4AEpAiCWwZhSXgxGOYO%2B1SypfL8AL5xsWz%2BppTwpCXZcgOhGdZ7ndeghAFdqtXxD/ICwL1%2B8rpeAwWDELQPy3rXo%2BgummaT9Ps/zyPBeMpWq/xOvRgL1vDaVhhNYrd1Fxtu3hEXKgeDoD66CoK74qlRkABejLURaVoKM%2BH9f2XHgTG6ZnrxG/PCJuq0nTdUcv9R4llSy3lOGYeCD8f5Ah8nNACz4MEs3jj9W29t%2BRTz3nPA%2Bm8x5/AALR3ENqVPBFlgEMA9u1L26Fb73xDM/LA9CICcPQK6FI/88Cf0lMcRhipRGALEMw1qi1dy7xnuQ4Ah8qG0JtLwxBVptq4MtECJhICCFBXYYRGIqBPDcL%2BHgBQfxMAAEcvBiD7gQdAyo/YgEHsPHuhdBKHXKumQSxwMpZUwDlKSVxiAQNlFAwh9ViFKP3qoyhoIaF3BsXYxxzijrEFYUjUxq1%2B5V0wFqbxi8tjukSSotRqT47BSTk8H84Nkxpkbgos0SIUSmlccqDBz4zAaDMJIO4EivBUGMbyIpniBDSQEHqP4MQxlUHiDUwuFQFCVkWVQEy6BSxMDTLgsZZlpGtMTsrQinds5GDzuU94opkk%2BLBJpRi6z6nnMKT0lUlcQBXAggidW9N9o2mOBcE%2BJ8AUxVuFyFB/h7mrKeXKZ8EK%2BZgsYnClJDdqyn2fBJdFjy3mNzlBwVYtBODwV4H4DgWhSCoE4G4aw1hFRbxQbsHgpACCaGJasAA1iAeCkgTL%2BDMFIDQABOUVwr/Aci4IM/QnBJAUs5TSzgvAFAgCCByqlxLSBwFgDARAKBUAsBSHQOSFBKLGtNQkYAoquB8DoFaYgaqIAxCVTEcITQficDZWgFg2MCAAHkGCzyVVgFghhgDiC1aQfAgI6hXDVdG4ctQvBWiVT%2BLoSqxwxGREPDwWAlX6TwCwb12qqAGGAAoAAangTAtIA0ykpWy/gggRBiHYFIGQghFAqHUNG3QdqDBGBQAyyw%2Bg8AxDVZAVYpMeiJuodQvE8pTCWGsFwDkxxqEBrMKqro1wsguCnpMPwiR4LBCnoMcolQQBmA5KK1I6RMgCGPXoQoT6GCXuGAkRi0gah1AEH0CYng2hJDPX%2BnogG5hlC/Teu9Yx%2BgvrtTMfon7Fjfv8JIVYty9D6UwNsHgJKyWKujbSjgqhEj%2BGoRhk2yAwaipMlwY4EB6WrrHccXAhAJp7DtccDwlr6CQW48sXgmqtDLB5XyoIpKOAKtICWyQuwTK7HghyXY/hlOSFvbsUVkgz2UupaR1V6r2WctWLqg16wCAtwIOQSgvqTUCciKwbY5HKPUZTkKCAY0GDcuE8EfANx756BbcIUQ4hO0hZ7WoJVA7SC0mRCkUthGODktIPp3gpGA2pus1JKgxxXNUckDRujDGmN8Yc/EFlXA/Oia5aQWSTBp6UGS7Jkt8F/CCs0%2BpjDKnGIaHgnppVhnbDGdq%2BJ0gvLdNKY5Ke0VGgNAzd2GYRIorkjSd2MRgzKqTNavG9JndaWhvbbG6sSJGRnCSCAA%3D)

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <array>
#include <cstdio>

struct pmr_aware_container
{
    using allocator_type = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

    /* ctors */

    // default
    pmr_aware_container() : pmr_aware_container{allocator_type{}} {} // delegate to aa constructor

    explicit pmr_aware_container(const allocator_type alloc)
        : str_("Hello long string!!!", alloc) {
        printf("default constructor called!\n");
    }

    // copy
    // pmr_aware_container(const pmr_aware_container&) = default;

    pmr_aware_container(const pmr_aware_container& other, allocator_type alloc = {}) 
        : str_(other.str_, alloc) {
        printf("Copy constructor called!\n");
    }

    // move
    pmr_aware_container(pmr_aware_container&& other) noexcept
        : str_{std::move(other.str_), other.get_allocator() }
    {
        printf("Noexcept move constructor called!\n");
    }

    pmr_aware_container(pmr_aware_container&& other, const allocator_type& alloc)
        : str_(std::move(other.str_), alloc)
    {
        printf("Specific move constructor called!\n");
    }

    // assignement

    pmr_aware_container& operator=(const pmr_aware_container& rhs) = default;
    pmr_aware_container& operator=(pmr_aware_container&& rhs) = default;

    ~pmr_aware_container() = default;

    allocator_type get_allocator() const {
        return str_.get_allocator();
    }

    std::pmr::string str_ = "Hello long string!!!";
};


class LoggingResource : public std::pmr::memory_resource
{
public:
    LoggingResource(std::pmr::memory_resource *underlying_resource) : underlying_resource_{underlying_resource} { }

private:
    void *do_allocate(size_t bytes, size_t align) override {
        printf("Allocating %d bytes!\n", bytes);
        return underlying_resource_->allocate(bytes, align);
    }

    void do_deallocate(void*p, size_t bytes, size_t align) {
        underlying_resource_->deallocate(p, bytes, align);
    }

    bool do_is_equal(std::pmr::memory_resource const& other) const noexcept override {
        return underlying_resource_->is_equal(other);
    }

    std::pmr::memory_resource* underlying_resource_;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<std::byte, 2024> buf;
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mbs{buf.data(), buf.size()};

    LoggingResource log_resource{&mbs};

    std::pmr::vector<pmr_aware_container> v{ { pmr_aware_container{ &log_resource}, pmr_aware_container{ &log_resource} }, &log_resource};
}
```

After checking the binary I was quite surprised to find out that the virtual calls made by my LoggingResource were not actually devirtualized, even with the newest compiler gcc 12.1. I thought that this would happen as a requirement for pmr to be as fast as advertised. This is the respective vtable in the assembly:

```
vtable for LoggingResource:
        .quad   0
        .quad   typeinfo for LoggingResource
        .quad   LoggingResource::~LoggingResource() [complete object destructor]
        .quad   LoggingResource::~LoggingResource() [deleting destructor]
        .quad   LoggingResource::do_allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long)
        .quad   LoggingResource::do_deallocate(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long)
        .quad   LoggingResource::do_is_equal(std::pmr::memory_resource const&) const
```

I could see that there was an improvement from gcc 9.1 to 12.1 in that back then not even the monotonic buffer resource was devirtualized. Oputput for gcc 9.1:

```
vtable for std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource:
        .quad   0
        .quad   typeinfo for std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource
        .quad   std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource::~monotonic_buffer_resource() [complete object destructor]
        .quad   std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource::~monotonic_buffer_resource() [deleting destructor]
        .quad   std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource::do_allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long)
        .quad   std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource::do_deallocate(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long)
        .quad   std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource::do_is_equal(std::pmr::memory_resource const&) const
vtable for LoggingResource:
        .quad   0
        .quad   typeinfo for LoggingResource
        .quad   LoggingResource::~LoggingResource() [complete object destructor]
        .quad   LoggingResource::~LoggingResource() [deleting destructor]
        .quad   LoggingResource::do_allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long)
        .quad   LoggingResource::do_deallocate(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long)
        .quad   LoggingResource::do_is_equal(std::pmr::memory_resource const&) const
```

This could prove performance critical if I try to nest different memory allocators, like a pool allocator upon a monotonic buffer resource etc.. However, what made me curious is that `std::monotonic_buffer_resource` *did* actually devirtualize. How is this possible and how can I achieve the same for my allocators?

Comment: The presence of vtable may not be a bad thing. What function is actually called at the call site? I see `call    LoggingResource::do_allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long)` in godbolt

Comment: @Osyotr that is indeed what is called. Interestingly, do_deallocate is fleshed out in assembly but never called (even though it would be a no-op for the monotonic buffer)